# Profile data is not saving in Experience Profile

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

I am trying to save the data to the `Experience Profile` when the user submits the form, but the data is not getting displayed in the dashboard.

Below is my code for storing data:

```
public void IdentityUser(string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string PhoneNumber)
    {
      // identify the user
      Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("contactform",Email);
      // get the contact
      var contact = Tracker.Current.Contact;
      // get the personal facet
      var contactPersonalInfo = contact.GetFacet<IContactPersonalInfo>("Personal");
      // set the contact's name
      contactPersonalInfo.FirstName = FirstName;
      contactPersonalInfo.Surname = LastName;
      // get the email facet
      var contactEmail = contact.GetFacet<IContactEmailAddresses>("Emails");
      // Create an email if not already present.
      // This can be named anything, but must be the same as "Preferred" if you want
      // this email to show in the Experience Profiles backend. 
      if (!contactEmail.Entries.Contains("Personal"))
      {
        contactEmail.Entries.Create("Personal");
      }
      // set the email
      var email = contactEmail.Entries["Personal"];
      email.SmtpAddress = Email;
      contactEmail.Preferred = "Personal";
      IContactPhoneNumbers phoneNumberInfo = contact.GetFacet<IContactPhoneNumbers>("Phone Numbers");
      if (!phoneNumberInfo.Entries.Contains("Mobile"))
      {
        phoneNumberInfo.Entries.Create("Mobile");
      }
      var mobile = phoneNumberInfo.Entries["Mobile"];
      mobile.Number = PhoneNumber;

//abandoning session so the data get persisted straight into xDb. I have tried removing them as well no effect
          Sitecore.Context.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
          HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
        }
```

The Experience Profile looks like this:
[image]

I have updated my code as below after comments:

```
public void TrackAnonymousUser(string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string PhoneNumber)
    {
      if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew)
      {
        var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;

        if (manager != null)
        {
          // Save contact to xConnect; at this point, a contact has an anonymous
          // TRACKER IDENTIFIER, which follows a specific format. Do not use the contactId overload
          // and make sure you set the ContactSaveMode as demonstrated
          Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
          manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);

          // Now that the contact is saved, you can retrieve it using the tracker identifier
          // NOTE: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource is marked internal in 9.0 Initial - use "xDB.Tracker"
          var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference("ContactForm", Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

          // Get contact from xConnect, update and save the facet
          using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
          {
            try
            {
             //contact is null
              var contact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

              if (contact != null)
              {
                if (contact.Personal() != null)
                {
                  contact.Personal().FirstName = FirstName;
                  contact.Personal().LastName = LastName;
                }
                else
                {
                  client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, "MyFacetKey", new PersonalInformation()
                  {
                    FirstName = FirstName,
                    LastName = LastName,
                  });
                }
                if (contact.PhoneNumbers() != null)
                {
                  contact.PhoneNumbers().PreferredPhoneNumber = new Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PhoneNumber(string.Empty, PhoneNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                  client.SetFacet<PhoneNumberList>(contact, "MyFacetKey", new PhoneNumberList(new PhoneNumber(string.Empty, PhoneNumber), "mobile"));
                }
                if (contact.Emails() != null)
                {
                  contact.Emails().PreferredEmail = new EmailAddress(Email, true);
                }
                else
                {
                  client.SetFacet<EmailAddressList>(contact, "MyFacetKey", new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(Email, true), "email"));
                }
                client.Submit();

                // Remove contact data from shared session state - contact will be re-loaded
                // during subsequent request with updated facets
                //manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
              }
            }
            catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
            {
              // Manage conflicts / exceptions
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is that my contact object is null even after pushing it to the xConnect repository. 
I can see in the comments as below:

```
// Now that the contact is saved, you can retrieve it using the tracker identifier
          // NOTE: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource is marked internal in 9.0 Initial - use "xDB.Tracker"
          var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference("ContactForm", Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));
```

I am not too sure where to find xDB.Tracker I can't seem to have reference to it. Is that the reason for the contact is null?

Furthermore, I see the following in the `xConnect logs`:

```
2018-02-14 09:37:26.897 +10:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.AddContactOperation: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.EntityOperationException: Operation #0, AlreadyExists, Contact
2018-02-14 09:37:26.897 +10:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Facet]: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #1, ReferenceNotFound, Contact, Classification
2018-02-14 09:37:26.897 +10:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.EntityOperationException: Operation #0, AlreadyExists, Contact
```

Comment: Have a look at the documents for working with xConnect, https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/contact-facets/update-facets.html#setting-a-known-contact-s-facets. You need to write the data with the xConnect client as well as the cached facet values.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: @Gatogordo Sitecore version 9 initial release

Comment: In the initial release, you should use "xDB.Tracker" instead of Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource (as const string)

Comment: And btw.. the code is not ok - check the examples again. You are mixing known and anonymous contacts.. (as I metnioned in my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Facets that are loaded into session can be edited but are not saved to
>   xConnect on session end. You must use the xConnect Client API to
>   update facets.

Check the documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/contact-facets/update-facets.html).

You need to use XConnectClient and set your values there. Values set on the contact in session are not saved. This is a big difference between v8 and v9.

> You must update a contact’s facets directly in xConnect using the
>   xConnect Client API and manually update the copy of that facet that
>   exists in session. The tracker does not lock contact data, which means
>   that a contact with an ongoing session can still be updated by other
>   systems. Holding a facet in session and submitting that facet to
>   xConnect on session end could result in a conflict if a more recent
>   version of that facet is available.

Make sure to note the difference between anonymous and known contacts. The code is a bit different. The documentation mentioned earlier has good code examples that will get you going.

Comment: I have updated my code in the question itself. I am getting issue with contact being returned as null. It would be greatly appreciated if you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me in Sitecore 9 initial release:

```
public void TrackAnonymousUser(string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string PhoneNumber)
    {
        var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;

      if (manager != null)
      {
        // Save contact to xConnect; at this point, a contact has an anonymous
        // TRACKER IDENTIFIER, which follows a specific format. Do not use the contactId overload
        // and make sure you set the ContactSaveMode as demonstrated
        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
        manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact);


        // Now that the contact is saved, you can retrieve it using the tracker identifier
        // NOTE: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource is marked internal in 9.0 Initial - use "xDB.Tracker"
        var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference("xDB.Tracker", Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

        // Get contact from xConnect, update and save the facet
        using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
          try
          {
            var contact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());

            if (contact != null)
            {
              if (contact.Personal() != null)
              {
                contact.Personal().FirstName = FirstName;
                contact.Personal().LastName = LastName;
              }
              else
              {
                client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, new PersonalInformation()
                {
                  FirstName = FirstName,
                  LastName = LastName,
                });
              }
              if (contact.PhoneNumbers() != null)
              {
                contact.PhoneNumbers().PreferredPhoneNumber = new Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PhoneNumber(string.Empty, PhoneNumber);
              }
              else
              {
                client.SetFacet<PhoneNumberList>(contact, PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey, new PhoneNumberList(new PhoneNumber(string.Empty, PhoneNumber), "mobile"));
              }
              if (contact.Emails() != null)
              {
                contact.Emails().PreferredEmail = new EmailAddress(Email, true);
              }
              else
              {
                client.SetFacet<EmailAddressList>(contact, EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey, new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(Email, true), "email"));
              }
              client.Submit();

              // Remove contact data from shared session state - contact will be re-loaded
              // during subsequent request with updated facets
              //manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
            }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Log.Error("Error saving data to profile", ex, this);
            IdentityUserInSitecoreProfile(FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber);
            // Manage conflicts / exceptions
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new code, you use the same facet key `MyFacetKey` over and over again. Best to set a `DefaultFacetKey` on your custom facet classes and use those. On the standard classes, they're already implemented. So, for example, do this:

```
client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, new PersonalInformation()
              {
                FirstName = FirstName,
                LastName = LastName,
              });
```

So for all the other facets, also use `Facet.DefaultFacetKey` for these.

Also, when getting the contact, you won't get any facets unless you include them in the expand options; so change

```
 var contact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions());
```

to

```
 var facets = new string[] { PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey }; 
 var contact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(facets));
```

Now you can get the facet of the contact object and manipulate it.

**Example:**

```
// Within the client using

var facets = new string[] { PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey }; 
var contact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(trackerIdentifier, new Sitecore.XConnect.ContactExpandOptions(facets));

// Assuming contact != null
var personalInformationFacet = contact.GetFacet<PeronalInformation>(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey);

// Assuming personalInformationFacet != null
personalInformationFacet.FirstName = FirstName;
personalInformationFacet.LastName = LastName;

client.SetFacet<PersonalInformation>(contact,  PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInformationFacet);
await client.SubmitAsync();
```